# Can I create an array of arraylists of arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

What I want to create is a 10-element array that consist of arraylists. Also the arraylists should consist of 3-element(string) arrays. (Something like metroMap[10][?][3])
I learned that arraylist of arrays and array of arraylists are possible but what about the above example?

I tried creating it but I had trouble specifying the number of elements

```
ArrayList<String[]>[] metroMap = new ArrayList<String[]>[10][3];
/*
String[][] firstMetroline = new String[occurences(metrolines[0][2], ',')][3]; // creating arrays with the
String[][] secondMetroline = new String[occurences(metrolines[1][2], ',')][3]; // required sizes for
String[][] thirdMetroline = new String[occurences(metrolines[2][2], ',')][3]; // each metroline
String[][] fourthMetroline = new String[occurences(metrolines[3][2], ',')][3];
String[][] fifthMetroline = new String[occurences(metrolines[4][2], ',')][3];
String[][] sixthMetroline = new String[occurences(metrolines[5][2], ',')][3];
String[][] seventhMetroline = new String[occurences(metrolines[6][2], ',')][3];
String[][] eighthMetroline = new String[occurences(metrolines[7][2], ',')][3];
String[][] ninthMetroline = new String[occurences(metrolines[8][2], ',')][3];
String[][] tenthMetroline = new String[occurences(metrolines[9][2], ',')][3];
*/
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    String stationsString = metrolines[0][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < occurences(metrolines[j][2], ','); i++) {
        // further processing our data by storing each station and their coordinates as elements of our arrays
        if (stationsString.charAt(0) == '*') {
            metroMap[j][i][0] = stationsString.substring(1, stationsString.indexOf(' '));
            metroMap[j][i][2] = "Visible";
        } else {
            metroMap[j][i][0] = stationsString.substring(0, stationsString.indexOf(' '));
            metroMap[j][i][2] = "Invisible";
        }
        stationsString = stationsString.substring(stationsString.indexOf(' ') + 1);
        if (stationsString.indexOf(' ') != -1) {
            metroMap[j][i][1] = stationsString.substring(0, stationsString.indexOf(' '));
            stationsString = stationsString.substring(stationsString.indexOf(' ') + 1);
        } else
            metroMap[j][i][1] = stationsString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post photos of text. Edit your question to include your code.

Comment: Oh sorry, I will edit it right now.

Comment: Have a look at where you declare `metroMap`. You are declaring a one-dimensional array, but you are trying to set *two* dimensions.

Comment: An `ArrayList` is a `List` which uses arrays internally. It cannot be used like an array. I suggest you read some Java tutorials, e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html

Comment: I knew that wasn't right but that was what I could think of as closest to the correct way.

Comment: Ok I will check them out thanks

Comment: You might want to consider using Java’s object-oriented features to define a class (a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395), probably) to represent your data in a meaningful structure.

Comment: I suspect this could be the result of an [X-Y Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) . The O/P might have  wanted a 10 x N x 3 String array, but wasn't familiar with how to have the middle dimension variable. So, thought of mixing arrays and `List` Objects.  If this is correct, I suggest the title be changed to "Three dimension array with variable size of middle dimension", and the question body edited for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it was decided to add generics to Java, generics were implemented in a way that made them incompatible with arrays. So, a line like `ArrayList<String[]>[] metroMap = new ArrayList<String[]>[10][3];` would cause a compiler error: `Generic array creation`.

Without generics, you could have an array of `ArrayList`. And, each element in one of the `ArrayList` elements could be an array or another `List`. As you reference each element, you would want to use a cast.

```
    List[] mapMetro = new ArrayList [12];
    int stops;
    ... 
    String [][] foo = new String [stops][3];
    ... 
    mapMetro [0].add (foo);
    ... 
    String [][] bitter = (String [][]) mapMetro[i].get (j);
```

This is generally not advised. Search for "Java Don't use raw types in new code."

I've spent little time on this possibility, because I'd like to suggest an alternative: Simply use a "3D array".

Java doesn't have true multidimensional arrays. But, an array is a reference type. And Java allows arrays of reference types, so nested arrays are allowed.

One consequence is "ragged" arrays are allowed. For example, in a "2D array", row zero might have 12 elements, row one might have 2 elements, row 3 might have zero elements, row 4 might have 42 elements.

More to the point: The references can be manipulated to point to other Objects of the same type.

```
   String [][] foo = new String [10][12];
   String [] roadRunner = new String [18];
   ... // code to use foo and roadRunner
   foo [5] = new String [] {"Bugs","Daffy","Yosemite Sam"};
   foo [6] = roadRunner; 
   foo [7] = new String [7];
```

So, when you know `metroMap` will have `k` elements (lines), but each line has a different number of stations, you can delay declaring the number of stations until information for each line is available:

```
   String [][][] metroMap = new String [k][][];
   int stations;
   ... 
   for (int j = 0; j < metroMap.length; j++) {
     // put yourcode to get number of stations for line j here
     // I'll assume it is in variable "stations" 
     metroMap [j] = new String [stations][3];
     // your code to fill elements of  metroMap[j] here
   }
```

You can iterate over the array with nested loops:

```
  for (int j = 0; j < metroMap.length; j++) {
       for (int k = 0; k < metroMap[j].length; k++) {
           for (int m = 0; m < metroMap[j][k].length; m++) {
              String foo = metroMap [j][k][m];
              ...
           }
       }
   }
```

Or, using the enhanced for loop:

```
   for (String [][] stops: metroMap) {
       for (String [] aStation: stops) { 
           for (String foo: aStation) {
              ... 
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: I neglected to mention a third possibility: Java allows nested Collections: One could code `ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> foo;` for example.